# Bootstrap side bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

[image: How would I make it so the "CONTENT HERE" texts goes where the red box is?]
How would I go about making the CONTENT HERE text go in the red box area. I have tried almost any method I could possibly think of, but nothing worked. I even tried putting the text in a row and then set its class to "row pull-left". Here is my code:

```
 <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-12" style="padding:20px;">

            <!-- Search -->
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 pull-left">
            <div class="well" id="search_area">
            <div class="input-group ">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></span>
            <form action="" method="GET">    
            <input type="text" id="search_query" name="query" class="form-control" value="<?=$search_query?>">
            </form>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Search -->

            <!-- Sorting -->

            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 pull-left">
            <div class="well" id="sorting_area" style="overflow:auto;">
            <b class="sorting-title">Sorting</b>
            <hr class="hr-clear">
            <div class="col-md-6 pull-left">
            Category:
            <select class="form-control" style="height:30px;">
            <option value="php_scripts">PHP Scripts</option>    
            </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 pull-left">
            Order by:
            <select class="form-control" style="height:30px;">
            <option value="php_scripts">PHP Scripts</option>
            <option value="php_scripts">Wordpress Plugins</option>
            <option value="php_scripts">Wordpress Plugins</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Sorting -->

            <div class="row pull-left">
                CONTENT HERE
            </div>

            </div> <!-- /.col-lg-11 -->

        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Study this and try and implement your own version: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/

Comment: @ilovecode That was not very helpful, also - custom css is used and Im trying to accomplish a pure bootstrap solution.

Comment: Well it looks like it would help your situation, and you're not going to have a very good website if you don't write any of your own CSS and have a "pure bootstrap" one

Comment: It doesn't need custom classes or inline styles, just correct implementation of the grid system and proper use of the form classes and structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is not the correct way of using the columns, nesting, and forms of Bootstrap 3. Use the correct classes on the form elements -- avoid inline styles -- and you will get good styling and spacing. You were missing form-group and didn't use any label. You the nesting of the columns and the extra rows was not correct and used `pull-left` on a column that is already floated left, but when you use the pull-left on it, it screws up on small viewports.

### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/yokuz/1/

```
 <!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <!-- Search -->
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <div class="well" id="search_area">
            <div class="input-group ">
               <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></span>
               <form action="" method="GET">    
                  <input type="text" id="search_query" name="query" class="form-control" value="<?=$search_query?>">
               </form>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- Search -->
         <div class="well" id="sorting_area">
            <b class="sorting-title">Sorting</b>
            <hr class="hr-clear">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label>Category:</label>
                     <select class="form-control">
                        <option value="php_scripts">PHP Scripts</option>
                     </select>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label>Order by:</label>
                     <select class="form-control">
                        <option value="php_scripts">PHP Scripts</option>
                        <option value="php_scripts">Wordpress Plugins</option>
                        <option value="php_scripts">Wordpress Plugins</option>
                     </select>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- Sorting -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
         This is where I put content
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- /.row -->
</div>
<!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

Comment: You're welcome. Read this: http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: http://www.bootply.com/b1kLe7rntz

Unless you're willing to go through every inch of the bootstrap.css or the LESS project, custom CSS is your best bet.